# I'm trying to understand Python's exec() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a string which is a function like

```
code = """def somefn(x):
    return x + x
    y = somefn(z)"""
```

and I am trying to run this in another function like

```
def otherfn(codestr):
    z = 2
    exec(codestr)
    return y

otherfn(code)
```

but it gives me the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/heh.py", line 11, in 
>   otherfn(code)
>   File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/heh.py", line 9, in otherfn
>   return y
>   NameError: name 'y' is not defined

it works fine outside the function like

`z=2
exec(codestr)
print(y)`

it finds y just fine but not sure why it is bugging out when it is in the function.

How can I fix this? Is it something to do with globals() and locals()? Using Python 3.6 btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. First of all, you have an indentation problem - the `y` gets 'defined' inside the `somefn()` function, after the `return` so it never actually gets the chance to get onto the stack. You need to redefine your `code` to :

```
code = """def somefn(x):
    return x + x
y = somefn(z)"""
```

But that's just the tip of the iceberg. The greater issue is that `exec()` cannot modify the local scope of a function. This is due the fact that Python doesn't use a `dict` for lookup of variables in the local scope so all changes from the `exec()` do not get reflected back to the stack to enable lookup. This causes a *weird* issue where `exec()` seemingly changes the `locals()` dictionary, but Python still throws a `NameError`:

```
def otherfn(codestr):
    z = 2
    exec(codestr)
    print(locals()["y"])  # prints 4
    return y  # NameError

otherfn(code)
```

This is an intended behavior, as explained in the [issue4831](https://bugs.python.org/issue4831), and further pontificated in the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

> **Note**: The default *locals* act as described for function [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) below: modifications to the default *locals* dictionary should not be attempted. Pass an explicit *locals* dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on *locals* after function [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) returns.

But if you have to reflect the changes you can just do a post-exec local scope update:

```
def otherfn(codestr):
    z = 2
    locals_ = locals()
    exec(codestr, globals(), locals_)
    y = locals_["y"]
    return y

otherfn(code)
```